# Can sIFR show fonts on a blue line (like writing on notebook paper)?

Tags: sifr

I encountered a use case where the business would like to display an answer to a question in a handwritten font.  So, my initial thought was to use sIFR, but the other part of the use case is they want the handwritten font on blue lines, analogous to writing in a paper notepad or notebook.  Can sIFR do a stylized font + notebook lines, or do I need to use another technique?  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can follow the tutorial here to get your blue lines in place: [Use custom type with sIFR](http://www.netmag.co.uk/zine/flash-1/use-custom-type-with-sifr)

However, I would caution against the use of sIFR for whole paragraphs of text. Mike Davidson mentions this in his best practices [here](http://www.mikeindustries.com/blog/sifr/).

Answer (score 0):

Raithlin,
Thanks for the link to the article.   I read Mike Davidson's page, and I am aware of the problems with replacing too much text.  It is something I will warn the business users about.